# Trying to scroll to a particular div using react-scroll

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll

I'm trying to scroll to a particular div from my navbar on my react app. 
I used react-scroll but still having issues scrolling to the div.
My navbar code was this.

```
<Nav className="mr-auto">
    <ScrollLink 
    to="contact" 
    spy={true} 
    smooth={true} 
    duration={500} 
    className='Home' 
    activeClass='Home'>
    Contact
  </ScrollLink></Nav>
```

And the div code was

```
<Element id='contact' name='contact'>
** My div here
</Element>
```

I tried using anchor tags with an Onclick event using a scroller.scrollTo method as well, didn't yield any results.

```
scroller.scrollTo('contact', {
  duration: 1500,
  delay: 100,
  smooth: true,
  offset: 50
});
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Using [react-scroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll) **v1.7.16**, Try this:

```js
import { Link, Element, Events, scrollSpy } from "react-scroll"

class App extends React.Component {

  // Optional: if you want to do some stuff when the event begin/end
  componentDidMount() {
    Events.scrollEvent.register("begin", function(to, element) {
      console.log("begin", arguments)
    })

    Events.scrollEvent.register("end", function(to, element) {
      console.log("end", arguments)
    })

    scrollSpy.update()
  }
  // Remove the event listener to avoid memory leaks and side effects 
  componentWillUnmount() {
    Events.scrollEvent.remove("begin")
    Events.scrollEvent.remove("end")
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Link
          to="myElement"
          spy={true}
          smooth={true}
          duration={500}
        >
          Scroll to element
        </Link>

        <Element name="myElement" className="element">
          Element
        </Element>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default App
```

Here is a working [codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-scroll-5m37j) example.

---

However you don't need a library to do so, you can simply give your targeted `div` a unique `ID` selector:

```html
<div id="mydiv" />
```

Then target it with `a` tag like so:

```html
<a href="#mydiv" />
```

Finally add this to your css:

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

```js
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
     <a href="#elementID">Scroll to your div</a>
     <div style={{height: 500}} />
     <div id="elementID">my div!</div>
     <div style={{marginTop: 500}} />
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render( <App /> , document.getElementById('root'))
```

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```